# In Visual Studio, C++ Build Configuration types are Debug, Debug3D, DebugDLL4, DebugDLL9, DebugDX, dxDebug and etc. What is the difference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

In Visual Studio, C++ Build Configuration types are Debug, Debug3D, DebugDLL4, DebugDLL9, DebugDX, dxDebug and etc.
What is the difference?

Comment: Check what properties are used accordingly. These aren't standard build confugurtions but someone created these.

Comment: Debug and Release are the standard configuration names.  A programmer can add as many as he wants, you will have to ask him why he thought that was a good idea.  With name choice like that, some odds you'll never hear back though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking at a specific project and not something generic. When you work on a Visual Studio project you can create and name as many configurations as you like. Each configuration name indicates its purpose so you may assume that the configurations you named are all based on the generic DEBUG configuration but each of them was created for different purposes. IN the code you can place preprocessor directives which will be used only when a certain configuration is used. For example:

```
#if DEBUGDx
// place your code here
#endif
```

Comment: That assumes that the configurations actually defined preprocessor symbols named after their names. There is no such guarantee. Preprocessor symbols and configuration names are unrelated entities.

Comment: You are right about that however I can't think of other uses of so many configurations unless you actually use them...

Comment: A configuration is the entirety of all compiler and linker settings. Singling out preprocessor symbols is unduly biased.

Comment: Well, I use new pre-defined configurations for such purposes (i.e. tests, special conditions, etc. ) but by default you would have DEBUG and RELEASE and 32 or 64 bit (which makes it 4 configurations).

Comment: Plus a configuration that uses a DirectX9-based renderer, a configuration using a DirectX-11-based renderer, one with an OpenGL-based renderer. And any number of other library dependencies. Just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

We can custom build configurations, for example, we have different clients, we want our app to behave differently for each one, we could custom build configuration for every client.

For detailed information, reference:

http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/custom-build-configurations-visualstudio/

Generally the app like C# has two configurations Debug and release, my understanding is that this project is not created by yourself, maybe created by other developers, if possible, you could discuss with them directly, I think you could get more detailed information about the different configurations. We just provide the possible reasons for it.

To really understanding this configuration:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396